# Excluding DataContract Name from return JSON

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have the following DataContract in my WCF service

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = Constants.ContractNamespace)]
    public class MyResponse
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ResponseCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<MyObject> MyObjects  { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And when I then use that as a return type from one of my OperationContracts like this

```
[OperationContract]
MyResponse ValidateById(string id);
```

I then get the following response

```
{"MyResponse":{"MyObjects":null,"ResponseCode":"ERR001"}}
```

is there any way to make this just return the properties so it would be like

```
{"MyObjects":null,"ResponseCode":"ERR001"}
```

**Update:**
I am also using transportClientEndpointBehavior

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpointBehavior_IMyService">
      <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
        <tokenProvider>
          <sharedAccessSignature keyName="RootManageSharedAccessKey" key="keyhere" />
        </tokenProvider>
      </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

and a netTcpRelayBinding

```
<netTcpRelayBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpRelayBinding_IMyService"/>
  </netTcpRelayBinding>
```

Comment: If you are using netTCP bindings, why not use SOAP rather than JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Body Style attribute to set wrapped response or not from your config file.
e.g.

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebWithDefaults">
        <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"
                 defaultBodyStyle="Bare" />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Above code assumes webHttp protocol. You can change it to yours

Comment: Thanks Patel, how does that work when using transportClientEndpointBehavior? I will update the question

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with my data contract.

I showed the wrong one above it is actually

```
   [DataContract(Name = "MyResponse", Namespace = Common.Constants.ContractNamespace)]
public class MyValidateModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public MyResponse MyResponse { get; set; }
}
```

but it needs to be

```
   [DataContract(Name = "MyResponse", Namespace = Common.Constants.ContractNamespace)]
public class MyValidateModel : Common.MyResponse
{
}
```